# Hourly or daily power consumption or power average consumption

Tags: power-management, powertop

I've read countless posts about reducing power consumption, and that's not why I'm here.

I'm looking to get daily or hourly power usage statistics, so that I can estimate the cost of keeping equipment running 24/7.

How do I do that??

I don't need an exact value, I'm ok with a good estimate.

I've looked into `powertop` and `/sys/class/powercap/*/energy_uj`, but I don't know if I'm reading those correctly, for example:

powertop says I use 351J for a sample of 60 seconds:

```bsh
$ powertop -t 60 -C powertop.csv ; cat powertop.csv | grep 'The power consumed was'
modprobe cpufreq_stats failedLoaded 65 prior measurements
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask d
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask d
Devfreq not enabled
glob returned GLOB_ABORTED
Preparing to take measurements
To show power estimates do 250 measurement(s) connected to battery only
Taking 1 measurement(s) for a duration of 60 second(s) each.
 the port is sda
PowerTOP outputing using base filename powertop.csv
The power consumed was :  351  J;
```

for the same 60 seconds interval, all the energy_uj files give a completely different value:

```bsh
$ v0=$(cat /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl\:0/energy_uj); \
  v00=$(cat /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl\:0\:0/energy_uj); \
  v01=$(cat /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl\:0\:1/energy_uj); \
  sleep 60; \
  v1=$(cat /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl\:0/energy_uj); \
  v10=$(cat /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl\:0\:0/energy_uj); \
  v11=$(cat /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl\:0\:1/energy_uj); \
  echo "(($v1 - $v0) + ($v10 - $v00) + ($v11 -$v01)) / 1000000" | bc -l
132.10661700000000000000
```

Thanks all!